# select concat with in-Tag

Tags: mysql, sql, select, concatenation

How can I form the following statement in MySql, that it will work?

```
select a,b,c from xx where a in concat(select y from abc where x='a','%');
```

Notice: The subquery returns more than one line!

Example

```
|---A----|
|/backup/|
|/foto/  |
```

And the `a in concat` should return all items where the subquery is like the following example:

```
|/backup/23/x.txt |
|/backup/xx/asdf  |
|/backup/x.txt    |
```

That's the reason why I need the concat!

Comment: i tried to understand but i couldnt

Comment: Can you include some sample table data for `xx` and `abc`?

Comment: You can generate a prepared statement using the group_concat function.  Or a REGEX function would probably get you where you are going, too.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell exactly what you are after here because your example data appears to contradict your question, but I think you need to use the `EXISTS` clause, rather than `IN`:

```
SELECT  a, b, c
FROM    xx
WHERE   EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    abc 
            WHERE   abc.x = 'a'
            AND     xx.a LIKE CONCAT(abc.y, '%')
        );
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/399f2/2)**